# AngularJS can not read property id of undefined Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am getting the error "can not read property id of undefined" in AngularJS.

We have two API End point,

i> `GET http://127.0.0.1:8088/api/information/` to fetch the data from JSON.

ii> `DELETE http://127.0.0.1:8088/api/information/:id` to delete the data of that particular id.

I have created a table, where datas will display in row. There is a checkbox to select row and a Delete button.

I am performing three operations,

i> Ftech the data in table. 
ii> Click on checkbox to select that row.
iii> Click on the DELETE button to delete that data from display and hit the DELETE api end point to delete from server too. 
iv>Refresh the page and fetch the data again.

Here is the JSON :-

```
{
  "1": {
    "venture": "XYZ Informatics",
    "member": [
      {
        "name": "abcd",
        "email": "abcd@gmail.com"
      }
    ],
    "message": "This is good day",
    "isclicked": false
  },
  "2": {
    "venture": "BBC Informatics",
    "member": [
      {
        "name": "xyz",
        "email": "xyz@gmail.com"
      }
    ],
    "message": "This is bad day",
    "isclicked": true
  }
}
```

Here is the code :-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="MyApp">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      table, th, td {
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      }
      th, td {
      padding: 15px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="displayController">
      <table style="width:100%">
        <tr ng-repeat="data in datas">
          <td>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="data.clicked">
          </td>
          <td>{{ data.id }}</td>
          <td>{{ data.venture }}</td>
          <td>{{ data.message }}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <button ng-click="delete()">DELETE</button>
    </div>
    <script>
      angular.module('MyApp', [])
      .controller('displayController', function($scope, $http) {
      var url = "http://127.0.0.1:8088/api/information";
      $http.get(url).success(function (response) {
      $scope.datas = response;
      });

      //To Delete 
      $scope.delete=function(){
      angular.forEach($scope.datas, function(val, key){
      if(val.clicked){
      delete $scope.datas[key] 
      var userId = $scope.data.id; //It is coming from {{ data.id }}
      $http.delete('http://127.0.0.1:8088/api/information/:' + userId) //DELETE API end point
          .success(function (response) {
             $scope.refresh(); //Refresher function
          });

      $scope.refresh = function(){
      var url = "http://127.0.0.1:8088/api/information"; //Fetch the updated data
      $http.get(url).success(function (response) {
      $scope.datas = response;
      });
      }

      }
      })
      }

      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: code formatting sucks. will not read

Comment: please post the *entire* error.  specifically, the line number where the error occurs.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined at (index):19

Comment: There is no `$scope.data`. Use the object instance in the loop

Comment: you don't have a `$scope.data` property.  you have a `$scope.datas` property; `data` is an individual iteration of `datas`.

Comment: Even if I take $scope.datas.id , it is showing the same

Comment: I got it, replaced it with $scope.datas[0] , now I am getting http://127.0.0.1:8088/api/information/:[object%20Object]  400 bad request error

Answer (score 0):

Not near a computer to properly test your code, but a first read left me with this: When you do `delete $scope.datas[key]`, you are destroying the `data` object. So when you try to assign `userId`, the object you are trying to access doesn't exist. My recommendation would be to only do a local item removal on a successful server DELETE. Try moving `delete $scope.datas[key]` into the success function.

On a separate note, `.success()` is deprecated, and it is preferred to use the ES6 Promise compliant `.then(successfn, errorfn)` form. See more [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).